# Expectation of the Pareto distribution

Tags: pareto-distribution

I would like to know if my understanding of the following is correct. This has been tripping me up for a long time now.

Compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x^{1-\beta}$.

This is part of a homework problem regarding the expectation of the Pareto distribution. It says everywhere that the expectation is for $\beta>1$ only, but what about $B=1$? Then doesn't the expectation change significantly because the limit at $\beta = 0$ evaluates to 1?

Could someone please clarify my doubt? Thanks.

Comment: If this is for the purposes of study, please add the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag

Comment: Because a request for clarification of this question was made in an answer and no response was received, I have added to the votes to close as unclear, in the sincere hope it will be improved.

Comment: @whuber - it seems to me that he's asking what that limit has to do with the expectation of the Pareto when $\beta = 1$.  I agree it's a little unclear, but...  to the OP: if what I've written is correct, it would improve your question considerably if you put an explicit statement to that effect in place of the "... clarify my doubt?" line.

Comment: @jbowman The problems with notation pointed out by Glen_b need fixing, too.

Comment: @whuber No disagreement there.  Plus the tag...  OK I withdraw my comment, but I'll leave it up as a potentially useful guide to the OP on what to fix.

Comment: OK all, I resolved my doubt somehow. Sorry, I hadn't worded it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your value of $\beta$ is a fixed quantity, taken as being known to be $>1$.

I am not sure how $B$ comes in. What is $B$ here? Did you mean $\beta$?

In the case where $\beta=1$ is doesn't have a mean. When $\beta>1$ it does. Find it for $\beta>1$.

There's no issue with 'changing significantly' because $\beta$ doesn't vary in this calculation. (The particular limit in your question exists for $\beta>1$ but $\beta$ is fixed when evaluating tha limit ($x$ is the variable), and is taken to be $>1$ for the purpose of this part.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Comment: To extend the answer slightly - the point about the limit is that it shows that the expectation is infinite for $\beta = 1$, as $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a x^{1-\beta}\text{d}x = \infty$.  (Note since $x^- = 0$, technically $x$ has an infinite mean rather than not having a mean at all.)